# Using Thorlabs Kinesis Brushed Motor Controller

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to use Thorlabs Brushed Motor Controller with Raspberry Pi 4, Model B. But its own software is Windows based and so their .dll files are Windows based too I suppose. I am trying to use some libraries like pylablib and thorpy I couln't move the stage. I am sharing the example codes that I wrote.

```
from thorpy.comm.discovery import *
from thorpy import *

if name == 'main':
    from thorpy.message import *

    stages = list(discover_stages())
    print(stages)
```

When I tried to run this code it turns me empty series. Like []

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_float, c_int, POINTER

# Load the Thorlabs Kinesis DLL
kinesis = cdll.LoadLibrary("Thorlabs.MotionControl.KCube.BrushlessMotor.dll")

# Connect to the Kinesis controller
serial_number = 27001111  # Replace with the serial number of your controller
kinesis.CC_Open(serial_number)

# Set the motor speed
kinesis.CC_SetVelocityParams(serial_number, 0, 100, 100)

# Move the motor forward
kinesis.CC_MoveWithVelocity(serial_number, 0, 1)

# Wait for the motor to finish moving
while kinesis.CC_CheckStatus(serial_number, 0, 0) == 3:
    pass

# Move the motor back
kinesis.CC_MoveWithVelocity(serial_number, 0, -1)

# Wait for the motor to finish moving
while kinesis.CC_CheckStatus(serial_number, 0, 0) == 3:
    pass

# Disconnect from the controller
kinesis.CC_Close(serial_number)
```

for example when I use this code I got invalid ELF error so... I don't know what can I do. Can you guys please help ? What can I do else can you give me any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Welcome. "Invalid ELF" implies there are binaries used that were not compiled on or for the Pi -- perhaps the `.dll`.  Where did you get that?

Comment: `I couln't move the stage` ... what's a `stage`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it's done in thorpy, but pylablib on Linux would use a standard  serial port interface. Therefore, first you need to figure out which device path (e.g., `dev/ttyUSB0`) corresponds to the controller, e.g., by plugging and unplugging it. Then you can supply this path when opening the connection:

```py
conn = {"port":"/dev/ttyUSB0","baudrate":115200,"rtscts":True}  # intead of ttyUSB0 use the correct path
dev = Thorlabs.KinesisMotor(("serial",conn))  # can also be, e.g., KinesisPiezoMotor, depending on the device kind
```